# @OneToMany relationship with @JoinTable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have created a new table for the `@OneToMany` relationship. Below is the liquibase script for creating a new table. The new table contains the ids from the other two tables.

```xml
<changeSet id="1" author="XXX">
   <comment>create table for UEN-ORG_C</comment>
   <createTable tableName="UEN_ORG_C">
      <column name="ORG_DTLS_ID_N" type="BIGINT">
         <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
      </column>
      <column name="ORG_CODE_ID_N" type="BIGINT">
         <constraints  nullable="false" />
      </column>
   </createTable>
   <addForeignKeyConstraint
      constraintName="FK_ORG_DTLS"
      referencedTableName="ORG_DTLS"
      baseColumnNames="ORG_DTLS_ID_N"
      baseTableName="UEN_ORG_C"
      referencedColumnNames="ID_N" />
   <addForeignKeyConstraint
      constraintName="FK_ORG_CODE"
      referencedTableName="ORG_CODE"
      baseColumnNames="ORG_CODE_ID_N"
      baseTableName="UEN_ORG_C"
      referencedColumnNames="ID_N" />
</changeSet>
```

below is the entity class:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
@Table(name = "ORG_DTLS")
public class OrganizationDetails implements BaseEntity<Long> {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "ID_N")
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany
   @JoinTable(name = "UEN_ORG_C",
              joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ORG_DTLS_ID_N")},
              inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ORG_CODE_ID_N")})
   private List<OrgCode> orgCodes;
}
```

While saving ORG_DTLS I should be able to select multiple ORG_CODES and same ORG_CODES can be selected by while creating ORG_DTLS
Example:

```
 ORG_DTLS_ID_N ORG_CODE_ID_N 
      82             21 
      83             21 
      84             21 
      85             25 
      86             25 
      87             25 
      88             25
```

When I try to save the IDs of two table into a new table with onetomany relationship. I'm getting below exception while saving data

```
ChangeEntityCommand ID: 48ab032d-c226-4d5a-af8a-38bca7b79735
2019.11.30;12:17:09 [http-nio-8092-exec-1] [rootId:  parentId:  eventId: ] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - insert into uen_org_c (org_dtls_id_n, org_code_id_n) values (?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into uen_org_c (org_dtls_id_n, org_code_id_n) values (?, ?)
2019.11.30;12:17:09 [http-nio-8092-exec-1] [rootId:  parentId:  eventId: ] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [128]
2019.11.30;12:17:09 [http-nio-8092-exec-1] [rootId:  parentId:  eventId: ] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [31]
2019.11.30;12:17:09 [http-nio-8092-exec-1] [rootId:  parentId:  eventId: ] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - insert into uen_org_c (org_dtls_id_n, org_code_id_n) values (?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into uen_org_c (org_dtls_id_n, org_code_id_n) values (?, ?)
2019.11.30;12:17:09 [http-nio-8092-exec-1] [rootId:  parentId:  eventId: ] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [128]
2019.11.30;12:17:09 [http-nio-8092-exec-1] [rootId:  parentId:  eventId: ] TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [30]
2019.11.30;12:17:09 [http-nio-8092-exec-1] [rootId:  parentId:  eventId: ] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - SQL Error: 1, SQLState: 23000
2019.11.30;12:17:09 [http-nio-8092-exec-1] [rootId:  parentId:  eventId: ] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - ORA-00001: unique constraint (AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE.PK_UEN_ORG_C) violated

2019.11.30;12:17:09 [http-nio-8092-exec-1] [rootId:  parentId:  eventId: ] INFO  o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl  - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2019.11.30;12:17:09 [http-nio-8092-exec-1] [rootId:  parentId:  eventId: ] ERROR o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl  - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
2019.11.30;12:17:09 [http-nio-8092-exec-1] [rootId:  parentId:  eventId: ] INFO  s.g.m.m.c.f.UserSessionInterceptor  - request and response is completed
2019.11.30;12:17:09 [http-nio-8092-exec-1] [rootId:  parentId:  eventId: ] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE.PK_UEN_ORG_C) violated
```

Comment: `ORA-00001: unique constraint` - says your log

Comment: Besides - what is the point of joining table if you don't have many-to-many relationship?

Comment: @Andronicus How can I save IDs from other two tables to new table without joining the table?

Comment: by using foreign key

Comment: @Andronicus could you please show me the sample? ORG_DTLS_ID_N should be unique. While saving ORG_DTLS I should be able to select multiple ORG_CODES and same ORG_CODES can be selected by while creating ORG_DTLS 
Example:
ORG_DTLS_ID_N  ORG_CODE_ID_N
          82                      21
          83                      21
          84                      21
          85                      25
          86                      25
          87                      25
          88                      25

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: @beginner using a join table is not necessarily bad if you don't want the orgcode table to be aware, and thus have an FK to orgdetails. But you need to read the error you get, and investigate and act accordingly. You're trying to save the same association between an orgdetails and an orgcode twice.

Comment: @Andronicus I went through the link which you shared. My requirement is when I save ORG_DTLS data should be saved only in ORG_DTLS and UEN_ORG_C table